# Android Cordova Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, reference, cordova

So my app that I am running from android 2.2 to 4.2 is acting pretty weird.
It is running on Cordova 2.3.0 with jQuery mobile latest version.

When I have the JavaScript in an external file "app.js" versions 2.2 and 3.2 work perfectly fine. Android versions 4.0 does not work with it in the external file. I don't get why this is not working, I have the file permission, and all the framework loaded properly.
What it does is on a button click it calls a method and thats the error I get.

The error is:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: detectBrowser1 is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/main.html"

detectBrowser1 is the method to detect the phone and set the screen size for the map they launched.

by the way, the index file points to main.html

I also get this error in Chrome as well but I just want it to work for android.

It seems like a permission error or something like that but I have the necessary permissions. I remember this working fine a couple days ago.

Comment: are you taking asynchronous loading into account?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? Probably not if I don't know what it means. @technosaurus

Comment: if you source a script it will load in parallel and embedded script will run before it gets loaded, there is no predictable way to know which will load 1st.  you can fix this by attaching an onload="myStartFunction()" or something to your sourced script tag(s)

Comment: The problem is I am not having the script load until its loaded, to cut down loading time. So onload would call functions i don't want loaded until they click a certain button. So I don't really know what to do and people say that it could be with loading time but I would leave it open for a bit to make sure it loads. or is that not a probable thing to do? @technosaurus